# Handle Julian and Real Times in one query

Tags: sql, sql-function, julian-date

Hi Below is some sample data

```
DECLARE @Time TABLE (
    [Time] VARCHAR(250),
    [Count] VARCHAR(250)
                 )
INSERT INTO @Time ([Time],[Count])
 VALUES 

('13:52','2'),
('13:53','2'),
('13:54','5'),
('13:55','3'),
('13:56','3'),
('13:57','1'),
('13:58','4'),
('13:59','1'),
('130','72'),
('1300','61'),
('1301','40'),
('1302','51'),
('1303','53'),
('1304','59'),
('1305','62'),
('1306','36'),
('1307','56'),
('1308','52')

Select * from @Time
```

Is there a way to handle both data types so that it outputs as a real time

I use a function that partly works but am getting and error each time:

```
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.
```

The function I use is as follows and wondered if this can be adopted/changed to account for the poor data eg both types of Times (Julian/Regular).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianTimeToSQLDateTime]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @JulianTime INT
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    IF @JulianTime >= 0 AND @JulianTime < 1440      -- this ensures that the result will be in the range of a datetime data type
        SET @Result = DATEADD(MINUTE, @JulianTime, CAST('00:00' AS TIME))
    ELSE
        SET @Result = CAST('00:00' AS TIME)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END


GO
```

ADDITION:
The COMPLETE datetime function is here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianDateTimeToSQLDateTime] (
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @JulianDate INT,
    @JulianTime INT = 0
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    IF @JulianDate > 640333     -- this ensures that the result will be in the range of a datetime data type
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = DATEADD(DAY, (@JulianDate-429), CAST('Jan 1 0001' AS DATETIME2))
            IF @JulianTime < 1440 AND @JulianTime >= 0      -- this ensures that the time is between 00:00 and 23:59
                SET @Result = DATEADD(MINUTE, @JulianTime, @Result)
        END
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 'Jan 1 1753'

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Comment: 1) What DBMS? 2) Are you able to change the datatype of the time column? Varchar() is horrible for holding a time, because it's simply a sometimes-convertible string. It would be so much easier to actually be dealing with a real time object.

Comment: Well, that and the count column. Neither of those should be varchar.

Comment: Appriciate the data types etc but this field is a Varchar(255) in the DW (Don't ask it just what I have to play with). The count is nothing and just the number of records it returned when I grouped the field. The main issue remain in that I need to somehow handle Julian and Real times stores in the same field

Comment: The first problem you're running into is that SQL can't convert the string '13:52' to an int. You've got a ton of behind-the-scenes data conversions going on that can easily bork up your expected results. @JulianTime is coming in as a string, being converted to an int then compared to a string that's being cast as a time that's then being set into a datetime. There are a lot of similar but different things there.

Comment: Also, that's a function, not a sproc.

Comment: You'll have to modify your function to accept a varchar, check for the ':' and then parse the time string for the different time parts. Then convert those into a julian format. Or the other way around. It would probably be easier to go from a julian to a time string, since you're end result needs to be a time anyway.

Comment: I completely understand about having to work with what's given to you. I've spent a career with "It is what it is.". There's definitely a difference in the way things were done and the way things should be done. :-) It was just an observation. If the data warehouse is dumping a time string into a varchar field, that could get quite a bit larger for a lot of records.

Comment: Cheers Shaun to be fair this is historical data and not what we currently use, so just working through the mappings and not going to be too concerned with a few data quality issues, If I spent time trying to resolve every data quality fix in the data I'd be doing nothing else (haha). As I say we extract that data out of a system as is and its stored as a Varchar. I need to map that into a valid Time so the user just see the Time element (eg 23:59 or 11:59PM)  Personally Id like to shoot the people who enter this tripe onto a system in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly are you trying to do from your give information. But I tried to modify the function to return time when I pass it JulianTime as a varchar. Here is the code -- (try to make changes accordingly though)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianTimeToSQLDateTime]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @JulianTime VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TIME(0)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result TIME(0), @HOUR VARCHAR(2), @MINUTES VARCHAR(2)
    -- DECLARE @JulianTime VARCHAR(255)
    -- SET @JulianTime = '13:02'
    SET @HOUR = SUBSTRING(@JulianTime, 1, 2)

    IF(LEN(@JulianTime) = 4)
        SET @MINUTES = SUBSTRING(@JulianTime, 3, 2)

    IF(LEN(@JulianTime) = 5)
        SET @MINUTES = SUBSTRING(@JulianTime, 4, 2)

    SET @Result = CONCAT(@HOUR, ':', @MINUTES)
    -- PRINT @RESULT
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the FUNCTION.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianTimeToSQLDateTime]
(
    @timeString varchar(250)
)
RETURNS TIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result TIME ;

    /* Ensure that we're working with a fixed date */
    DECLARE @epoch datetime = '19000101' ;

    /* Check the string for ':' */
    IF CHARINDEX(':',@timeString) > 0
        /* Can @timeString be parsed as a valid time? */
        SET @Result = TRY_PARSE(@timeString AS time) ; /* Returns NULL if bad time string. */
    ELSE
        /* No ':' so check if valid julian time. */
        IF TRY_CONVERT(int,@timeString) IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT(int,@timeString) BETWEEN 0 AND 1439
            SET @Result = CAST( DATEADD(minute, CONVERT(int,@timeString), @epoch) AS time) ;
        ELSE
            SET @Result = NULL ;

    RETURN @Result ;

END
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1ca82cd76b2932593262601b1742f602

This will only work if you're using something greater than SQL 2012+ because of TRY_PARSE and TRY_CONVERT. If you're lower than 2012, you can modify that bit to do what those functions essentially do.

Comment: NOTE: The function returns an actual time object, so it includes seconds. If you need to remove those, I'd do it in the display.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianTimeToSQLDateTimeSE, Line 19
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianTimeToSQLDateTimeSE, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: What database are you using? It looks like SQL Server, but if you're getting that error, it's 2008R2 or lower. You should be able to look at what 2012's TRY_ functions do and "reverse engineer" the functionality in them.

Comment: Yet its 2008 R2 matey and I don't have the authority for that I'm afraid, I'm just a new Developer one of a few within the organisation. I'm still waiting for a laptop I was promised at Christmas so I doubt they would invest in updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',[Time]) > 0 THEN CAST([Time] AS TIME) ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, TRY_CAST([Time] AS INT), CAST('00:00' AS TIME)) END AS [RealTime],
* 
from @Time
```

This appears to do the trick, thanks for the valuable input

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2008, use this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TR_PROTOS_JulianTimeToSQLDateTime]
(
    @timeString varchar(250)
)
RETURNS TIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result time ;

    /* Ensure that we're working with a fixed date */
    DECLARE @epoch datetime = '19000101' ;

    /* Check the string for ':' */
    IF CHARINDEX(':',@timeString) > 0
        IF ISDATE(@timeString) = 1
            /* Is @timeString a valid time object? */
            SET @Result = CAST(@timeString AS time) ; 
        ELSE 
            SET @Result = NULL ;
    ELSE
        /* No ':' so check if valid julian time. */
        IF ISNUMERIC(@timeString) = 1 AND CONVERT(int,@timeString) BETWEEN 0 AND 1439
            SET @Result = CAST( DATEADD(minute, CONVERT(int,@timeString), @epoch) AS time) ;
        ELSE
            SET @Result = NULL ;

    RETURN @Result ;

END
```

Comment: Wow thanks Shawn and works a treat. Is there any way your outstanding method can be adopted/expended for the full DateTime.

Comment: I have also added the additional CURRENT function for the datetime, this account for both fields, the issue when we used it was that the date part of it worked but the type conversion occurred in the time element and thus the reason it was concentrated on here in the first instance.

Comment: In addition the time IF NULL still needs to return 00:00:00.0000000 but still a fab function

Comment: Should be simple to change. Just modify any time datatypes to be datetimes, and make the function return a datetime datatype. Also, for the NULL result, just make it return a 0 time or the @epoch time or whatever time you want to illustrate as 0-time, since 0/0/0 00:00:00.000 is not a valid datetime.